# How can the Megaforce Power Rangers access the "Legendary" SPD and RPM powers?

Tags: power-rangers, power-rangers-megaforce

In Power Rangers Megaforce, the Rangers can access what is called "Legendary Mode" which gives them access to a wide range of powers.

How can they access SPD and RPM powers when [SPD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_Rangers_S.P.D.) is set in the future and [RPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_Rangers_RPM) is set in an alternate dimension/reality?

Answer (score 3):

Per the Power Rangers wiki;

> Legendary Ranger Mode, or simply Legendary Mode refers to the ability
>   of the Super Mega Rangers to morph into Historic Rangers, **via the
>   [Legendary Ranger Keys](http://powerrangers.wikia.com/wiki/Legendary_Ranger_Keys) and the [Legendary Morphers](http://powerrangers.wikia.com/wiki/Legendary_Morphers)**. They can
>   also use this mode to access new Ranger forms never before seen on
>   Earth.

No canon description seems to be offered as to how these 'keys' allow access to powers and ranger-types seen in other series.

---

Out of universe, the series was the latest in a long run of low budget shows. This meant that the production team had access to wide range of props and special effect systems.

Given their radically slashed budget, it made good sense to have a mechanism by which these could be reused without the need to over-explain why a prop had been recycled from an earlier [series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensou_Sentai_Goseiger).

Comment: The Morphing Grid must stretch across dimensions/realities, enabling the Rangers to call upon these other abilities.

Comment: 1) "latest", not "last" - they've since done several more years of shows.  2) The shows are not "low budget", which I suspect you intended in a somewhat negative way. Indeed, the series on which Megaforce was based had a huge cast, including many actors from past shows, so it (almost certainly) had a larger budget than past years.

Comment: @VBartilucci - The early shows were produced for less than £250K per episode. That's about the same as GoT's catering budget.

Comment: 250K was a great deal more money fifteen years ago. There's reports of more like $400K in recent years. Plus, I'll lay odds a great deal more of that budget can be seen on screen, so to speak - spent on effects, and not salaries, which makes up a great deal of the larger shows' budgets.

Comment: @VBartilucci - £250k wasn't a lot of money, even that long ago. The effects were pathetic, the shows were comprised heavily of pre-filmed footage recycled from episode to episode and the cinematography was practically non-existent.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add another out-of-universe explanation.

Power Rangers Super Megaforce is an adaptation of Taizoku Sentai Gokaiger, in which all of the Rangers from past Sentai seasons teamed up. Super Sentai has even more continuity problems with this than Power Rangers does (for example, about five different explanations for the extinction of the dinosaurs), but it was their 35th anniversary and they really wanted to bring *all* of the team is back. Similarly, it was important to the production team of Super Megaforce that *all* of the teams from past seasons of Power Rangers be included at some point.

Low budget is definitely a driving factor in Power Rangers, but the Legendary Ranger Keys came straight from Super Sentai and were probably motivated more by hype from past Rangers, ease of adaptation, and profit from collectible toys than keeping the budget down.

(As a side note, SPD and RPM are not mentioned by the Megaforce team as the teams appear on the cliffside, and Troy still says "They're all here".)

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE. Unless otherwise stated, questions are generally asking for in-universe answers.

Comment: I recall hearing reports that Saban asked Toei to film crowd-fight footage that only featured the Sentai teams from Zyuranger on, so there'd be no need to explain who those other dozen or so other teams were.

Answer (score 0):

SPD rangers and Time Force Rangers time travelled to the past before so the morphin grid has information on them.

As for RPM rangers, they share the same morphin grid as the Mega Force Rangers despite being on another dimension.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about this for a bit and I have a hypothesis for how it works. Assuming that each ranger team carries information about themselves in the morph, then when the SPD rangers traveled to the present (and when the RPM red ranger traveled to the “main” dimension) information about their morphs and teams were recorded. Of course, this assumes that the “legendary” ranger keys were to serve as more of an archive of the ranger teams and did so by seeing all morphing grid access in the history of that universe and that one rangers morph caries data about their entire team

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This site is designed around finding the best, most correct answer to a question.  Plain hypotheses don't work well, because there may be multiple hypotheses that all work, with no way to judge one better.  Do you have any evidence that your hypothesis might be true?